# CSS select second level elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to remove background on a second level `li` elements ?

```
<ul class="navi">
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li class="current">
        <a href="">Test</a>
        <ul class="navi2">
            <li class="current"><a href="">Remove bg</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Remove bg</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

I have tried to put `background-color: blue` instead of `background: none`, and it worked. I really don't know why.

Here is my CSS:

```
ul.navi {
    list-style: none;
    width: 247px;
}

ul.navi > li  {
    line-height: 36px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.navi > li > ul > li {
    background: none;   
}

ul.navi li a {
    display: block;
    color: #f4dfe8;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding: 0 0 0 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zhrgyLrf/

Answer (score 7):

Why not just set the background on the direct `a` child elements?

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/schr6zjh/)

```
ul.navi > li > a {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The reason `background: none` wasn't working is because you are setting the background on the entire parent, `li` element. Thus, even though the children don't have a background, the parent's background is still shown because it encompasses the children. As an alternative, you would have to set the children's background to `#fff`. In doing so, you would unfortunately lose your transparency, though.

Comment: And the last paragraph is precisely my answer ;). However, +1 from me.

Comment: @JacekKowalewski I gave your's a 1+ :p Not sure who downvoted it though. That's uncalled for.

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot, and good luck with answering another questions :). Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Your li is inside the red li. Try to just set another color, for example

```
ul.navi > li > ul > li {
    background: #fff;   
}
```

Color: transparent will also not work here... Because when You've got color: transparent, it is transparent, and the "below" red is visible underneath it.

Good luck, hope it helps.

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/zhrgyLrf/1/

Comment: How to make it work if first element uses background-image: url (...); instead of background-color ?

Comment: You can write: background-image: none; :). Remember to cancel only this property YOu want to cancel. In that case You have to cancel background-image, so type: background-image: none. In that case color will be the same, and only background-image will be removed :).

Comment: I have tried this. Here is your suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/u2nzkvcj/
(it does'nt work)

Comment: Ah, in that case, it works: there is no image, but still the image below is visible. Try to set: background-color: #60bddc; Sorry, but this is the only workaround for that... And it is not the most elegant one.

Answer (score 1):

IT happens because you ars setting the background to the entire `<li>` , and the second level is inside to the first , your second level has a transparent background and that's the reason because you see red (is the inmediately background set). You have 2 options:

1. set the background to the  elements
2. set a background matching to the original background

I recommend set the background to the  elements like this:

```
ul.navi > li  {
    line-height: 36px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul.navi > li > a {
 background-color: red;
    }
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zhrgyLrf/2/